# How to make a timeline with task and actions that is easily readible?

Tags: website-design, data-visualisation

We are making a web timeline for our callcenter department. In this timeline you can see tasks and related actions to perform these tasks. So task =actions+actions+ potential other actions or not.

Task infos = when + who(callcenter man/woman)+ beneficiary + what provider + what services + what periods + status
Actions infos = when + who(callcenter man/woman) + provider.

Example: Task : Create a new File/ Actions: receive the call + find the guy on our database + link the call and the file. Next task will be check its eligibility.

It is aimed to help the callcenter man to take note of the file before calling someone.

We've tried several attempts but all of them, for me, are unreadible.

FYI :it is not a call center to sell random stuff. We provide services for stricken people and it is paid by their insurance.

Any help? Tips? Another timeline seen on the web?

It will be a web technology timeline.

Comment: Hi JohnDoe, thanks for your question. Critique questions are a bit of a weird fit here, because they don't always match with our intended Q&A format. Please have a peek at [our guidelines for critique questions](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/682) and see whether you can make yours fit those. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a vertical timeline instead of a horizontal timeline.

In this way you have a "table view" which we're all much more familiar with for fast reading/scanning for information, and the space for text is significantly greater.

And we're all now familiar with this scrolling from using our phones the last 5+ years.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion - you might be dealing with a non-linear timeline when certain steps need to be repeated, such as insurance changing requirements or requesting additional supporting information from doctor's office, or patient changing their set billing preferences through the process.  So it's more of a logical flow chart with with loops and redirects where decision-making points have associated specific tasks.  If that is more in line with actual business processes used by your call center, you can search for "logical flow chart" to see examples.